# Remove redownloadable song form Itunes

Tags: iphone

how do I remove a redownloadable song.  I down loaded a song and it keeps charging me for it per month.  I want to remove it.

Comment: What is a `redownloadable song`?

Answer (score 1):

You may have subscribed to Apple Music, and are getting a charge for the monthly fee.
To cancel your subscription, follow the advice from this [Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202039):

1. On the Home screen, tap Settings.
2. Tap iTunes & App Store.
3. Tap your Apple ID at the top of the screen.
4. Tap View Apple ID. You might need to sign in.

[image]

5. Under Subscriptions, tap Manage.
   If you don't see a subscription in iTunes and are still being charged, make sure that you're signed in with the correct Apple ID. If so, you might have subscribed directly with the provider and not through iTunes. In this case, contact the content publisher or app developer directly to cancel your subscription.

[image]

6. Tap the subscription that you want to manage.
7. Use the options to manage your subscription. You can choose a different subscription period, or turn off Automatic Renewal.
   Turn off Automatic Renewal to cancel a subscription. Your subscription will stop at the end of the current billing cycle.

[image]